# SubInACL using accent in usergroup name returns error 1337

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, acl

I'm trying to reset my registry permissions to default because something modified it and causing some problems.

But when I replace the "Administrators" usergroup name with the translated one which would be "Rendszergazdák" and run the bat script I got error 1337 which looks like this:

If the file is saved as UTF-8 no-BOM

```
Elapsed Time: 00 00:00:00
Done:        0, Modified        0, Failed        0, Syntax errors        1
Last Syntax Error:WARNING : /grant=rendszergazdLookupAccountName : HKEY_CURRENT_
USER:rendszergazd+ík 1337 The security ID structure is invalid.
```

and if the file is saved in ANSI:

```
Elapsed Time: 00 00:00:00
Done:        0, Modified        0, Failed        0, Syntax errors        1
Last Syntax Error:WARNING : /grant=rendszergazd▀k=f : Error when checking argume
nts - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
LookupAccountName : HKEY_CURRENT_USER:rendszergazdßk 1337 
The security ID structure is invalid.
```

I tried to put the usergroup name between quotation marks but it didn't made any difference.

How can I use the translated name with Accents?

Comment: L33t, you know…

Answer (score 3):

I found out that you can use SID instead of user/usergroup name so I changed `administrators` with `S-1-5-32-544` and after this the script run just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day